# Yajara DataTable Filtration

Tags: javascript, laravel, yajra-datatable, laravel-datatables

Hey There Developers ,

I Am using Yajara Data Table Package for handling My Data .Now I am trying to add a filter that should give me the data based on the date Selected (I don't want the date Range Filtration) Suppose I had selected 7 October It should give me all the data that is being entered on 7th only That"s All

Thanks In advance Guys

I want only the data of a particular date which is being selected

Comment: You should try something and ask a real question if you face any issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller

```
$selectedDate = $request->input('selected_date'); //selected date '2023-10-07'
    
        $query = YourModel::query();
    
        if (!empty($selectedDate)) {
            $query->whereDate('created_at', $selectedDate

);
 return DataTables::of($query)
```

in your view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="selected_date">Select Date:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="selected_date" name="selected_date">
</div>
```

Ajax request

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '/url',
        data: function (d) {
            d.selected_date = $('#selected_date').val();
        }
    },
    columns: [columns]
});
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay ak This works for me well

Comment: ✌✔.............